# gsl::span fails to compile with std::regex

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, guideline-support-library

I'm trying to use `gsl::span` to pass some data from a packed structure of mixed binary/ascii data (hence no `vector` or `string`) to a function, where I want to operate on it with a regex, but I get the following errors:

> error C2784: 'bool std::regex_match(_BidIt,_BidIt,std::match_results<_BidIt,_Alloc> &,const std::basic_regex<_Elem,_RxTraits> &,std::regex_constants::match_flag_type)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::match_results>,_Alloc> &' from 'std::cmatch'
>
> see declaration of 'std::regex_match'

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <regex>
#include "gsl.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace gsl;

int main(int argc, const char **argv) 
{
    char lat[8] = { '0', '1', '9', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'E' };
    span<char> s = lat;

    // in a complex implementation this would be in a function,
    // hence the desire for span<>
    std::cmatch match;
    std::regex_match(s.begin(), s.end(), match, std::regex("[0-9]+"));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `std::regex_match` cannot resolve the function overload when the iterator type is `gsl::continuous_span_iterator` because `std::cmatch` uses a `const char*` as the iterator type. Neither `std::smatch` or `std::cmatch` is appropriate in this case, you need your own `std::match_results` type. Here's how it should be done:

```
#include <regex>
#include "gsl.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace gsl;

int main(int argc, const char **argv) 
{
    char lat[8] = { '0', '1', '9', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'E' };
    span<char> s = lat;
    std::match_results<decltype(s)::iterator> match;
    std::regex_match(s.begin(), s.end(), match, std::regex(".*"));
}
```

That said, at the time of this writing, the revised iterator approach still won't compile due to [issue #271](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/issues/271).

Until that's fixed, another workaround is:

```
int main(int argc, const char **argv) 
{
    char lat[8] = { '0', '1', '9', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'E' };
    span<char> s = lat;
    std::cmatch match;
    std::regex_match(&s[0], &s[s.length_bytes()], match, std::regex(".*"));
}
```

The workaround approach cover cases where spans of the same or different extents are passed to the function.